# Does anybody know what this symbol is?

Tags: telecommunication

The last couple of weeks, I've been noticing this (wifi like) symbol next to some of my contacts in my Android phone. The symbol I am interested about is in the red circle that has the outline of the wifi symbol.

[image]

I don't remember having enabled anything, so I am curious as to what it is and what does it mean (and whether I should disable it).

I tried looking, and I have a hunch it might be related to **wifi calling** but I can't be certain.

Apologies in advance, I know this does not fall strictly within the Engineering SE's jurisdiction, however, I know that I'll get an valid answer faster here that anywhere else.

Comment: Looks like android - which version specifically? Which carrier?

Comment: It's android version 11. The carrier is a Greek one (cosmote). It's a Xiaomi Poco X3 NFC.

Comment: Does this answer the question  https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232305

Comment: @AJN Only marginally. Apparently it's an OEM specific feature and not generic to android.

Comment: Hmm.. I use Google stuff a lot, it actually looks to me like the wifi symbol on chromebook (but not android). Maybe you can find it in [here (list of some droid status bar symbols)](https://en.droidwiki.org/wiki/List_of_symbols_in_the_notification_bar)? The wifi calling is supposed to have a telephone pictogram within it...

Comment: At least its not as obvious as I initially thought (I would have felt old and outdated - not that I am not). Anyway, I'll leave it a while longer here if you don't object, but eventually I might have to buy the bullet and migrate it to the android enthusiasts. However, it makes me think that a lot of things are pushed on users without never fully explaining what something is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This symbol means that the contact number you have called was connected via **Voice over WiFi (VoWiFi)** technology instead of VoLTE. Your service automatically shifts to VoWiFi whenever there is a WiFi network connection available if you turn the option of WiFi calling on.